# Issue with using component and forloop in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to create a component for division in VHDL, below is my code. I dont know where i am going wrong. My logic is:
At every step,
• shift divisor right and compare it with current dividend
• if divisor is larger, shift 0 as the next bit of the quotient
• if divisor is smaller, subtract to get new dividend and shift 1
as the next bit of the quotient.

I have used '-' sign here but in actual i have to use gates so either i have to use my subtraction component or just create a subtractor here.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

ENTITY divprog IS
 PORT(
    a: IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    b: IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    err: OUT std_logic;
    reslow: OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    reshigh: OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
END divprog;

architecture behaviour of divprog is
signal ax,bx,bsub,res :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal quo: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal intcarry: std_logic_vector(8 downto 0):= (others => '0');

BEGIN
--sub1: subtractor PORT MAP(aa,bb,x,ss);
Process is
variable i : POSITIVE := 1;
BEGIN
     ax <= "0000" & a;
     bx <= b & "0000";
    if(b > "0000") then

    while (i <=3) loop


        bx <= '0'&bx(7 downto 1);
        IF (ax < bx) then 
        quo <= quo(2 downto 0)& '0';
        --bx <= '0'&bx(7 downto 1);
        res <=ax;
       elsif(ax >= bx) then
        res <= ax - bx;
        quo <=quo(2 downto 0)& '1'; 
       end if;
    i := i + 1;
    ax <= res;
    end loop;
    reshigh <= quo;
    reslow <= res(3 downto 0);   
    end IF;
  wait for 100 ns;
END PROCESS;
end behaviour;
```

Can please someone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: In the code you just do a lot of operations and then wait 100ns. How do you check your code? Where is your test bench? To debug you should do steps one at a time. Try one operation see if it doe what you expect. Then try a second operation: again check. And so on...

Comment: Some recommendations: 1) Tell us what error message you are getting. 2) It is better to use the ieee.numeric_std package (instead of std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned) which provides signed and unsigned data types. 3) I guess your code will hardly be synthesizable. Is it intended for synthesis? Or just simulation? For synthesis you might want to create a more pipelined design.

Comment: My code complies but i get output as '0'. I am implementing this code just for simulation. When i run code with breaks at begin where i assign values to ax and bx it shows zero. I changed the logic as it was too complex for me and i just know basic vhdl.

Comment: New Code is below:
`architecture behaviour of divprog is
BEGIN
Process (a,b)
 variable count,X:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):= (others => '0');
 variable a1,b1,aa,bx,ss :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):= (others => '0');
 variable intcarry :std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):= (others => '0');
 BEGIN
if (a > b) then
      count   := "0000";
      while (a1 >= b) loop
            a1 := (a1 - b);
        count   := count + "0001";
      end loop;
    end if;
reslow<=a1;
reshigh<=count;
END PROCESS;
end behaviour;`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting a monolithic block of code in a comment. Please also use proper indentation, so we can read your code.

Answer (score 0):

The functional problem is related to variable `i`. It gets stuck at 4 after the first 100ns. It should be set to 1 between `BEGIN` and `END PROCESS`.

Comment: "maybe" and "guess" does not make an answer. This is more like a comment...

Comment: You're right, thanks. I edited my answer and this is the best I can do until I get full access for comments.